# the pandas function any() don’t return the result what i want

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, any

I have the following `DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'class': ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
        'item':  ['1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3','4','4','5','5','5','5','5','5','5'],
        'last_PO_code': ['103','103','103','104','103','103','104','105','106','103','103','104','103','103','104','105','105','106','1046'],
        'qty': [3,4,3,3,2,4,4,3,3,3,5,5,2,6,8,2,6,2,6],

    }
)
```

I apply the following rules for each unique item in the `item` column to this `DataFrame`:

1. `last_PO_code` has `'103'` only.
2. `last_PO_code` has (`'103'` & `'104'`) and (`qty` column of `'103'` > `qty` column of `'104'`)
3. `last_PO_code` has  (`'103'` & `'104'` & `'105'` & `'106'`) and (`qty` column of `'105'` == `qty` column of `'106'`) and (`qty` column of `'103'` > `qty` column of `'104'`)
4. `last_PO_code` don't have `'103'`
5. `last_PO_code` has (`'103'` & `'104'`) and (`qty` column of `'103'` == `qty` column of `'104'`)
6. `last_PO_code` has  (`'103'` & `'104'` & `'105'` & `'106'`) and (`qty` column of `'105'` == `qty` column of `'106'`) and (`qty` column of `'103'` == `qty` column of `'104'`)

I wrote the following code, but the result is not what I want.

```
regle1 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').all() else False
regle2 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').sum() > x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').sum() \
    else False
regle3 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('105').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('106').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').sum() > x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').sum() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('105').sum() == x['last_PO_code'].eq('106').sum() \
    else False
regle4 = lambda x: False if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() else True

regle5 = lambda x: True if (x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any()) \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').sum() == x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').sum() \
    else False
regle6 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('105').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('106').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').sum() == x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').sum() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('105').sum() == x['last_PO_code'].eq('106').sum() \
    else False

df2 = df.groupby(['class','item']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'regle1' : regle1(x),
                                  'regle2': regle2(x),
                                  'regle3' : regle3(x)
                                  }))
```

Only `regle1` does what I want for all items. For me the problem comes from the `any()` function. Either I use it badly or I don't understand it well.

What I have :

```
           regle1   regle2  regle3  regle4  regle5  regle6
class   item                        
0       1   True    False   False   False   False   False
        2   False   True    False   False   False   False
        3   False   True    True    False   False   False
        4   False   False   False   False   True    False
        5   False   True    True    False   False   False
```

What I want :

```
           regle1   regle2  regle3  regle4  regle5  regle6
class   item                        
0       1   True    False   False   False   False   False
        2   False   True    False   False   False   False
        3   False   True    True    False   False   False
        4   False   False   False   False   True    False
        5   False   False   False   False   True    True
```

All the mistakes I noticed were on item 5, but I don't understand why

Comment: You seem to have "value is 103 AND value is 104"  in all but the first rule. This can never be true. "value is 103 OR value is 104" could be true.

Comment: @doctorlove  - As you can see in output, it can. He don't have there `(x['last_PO_code'].eq('103') & (x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any()` but  `(x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any()` and `(x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any()` - so any of the values is equal 103 and any of the values is equal 104.

Comment: what does `qty 103 > qty 104` mean?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you are summing the number of `'last_PO_code'` instead of '`qty`'. In each lambda, you must have:

```py
(x['last_PO_code'].eq('103')*x['qty']).sum()
```

or as [`mozway`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) suggested, even better:

```py
x.loc[x['last_PO_code'].eq('103'), 'qty'].sum()
```

instead of:

```py
x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').sum()
```

The whole code:

```
egle1 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').all() else False
regle2 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any() \
    and (x['last_PO_code'].eq('103') * x['qty']).sum()  > (x['last_PO_code'].eq('104') * x['qty']).sum()  \
    else False
regle3 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('105').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('106').any() \
    and (x['last_PO_code'].eq('103')*x['qty']).sum() > (x['last_PO_code'].eq('104')*x['qty']).sum() \
    and (x['last_PO_code'].eq('105')*x['qty']).sum() == (x['last_PO_code'].eq('106')*x['qty']).sum() \
    else False
regle4 = lambda x: False if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() else True

regle5 = lambda x: True if (x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any()) \
    and (x['last_PO_code'].eq('103')*x['qty']).sum() == (x['last_PO_code'].eq('104')*x['qty']).sum() \
    else False
regle6 = lambda x: True if x['last_PO_code'].eq('103').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('104').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('105').any() \
    and x['last_PO_code'].eq('106').any() \
    and (x['last_PO_code'].eq('103')*x['qty']).sum() == (x['last_PO_code'].eq('104')*x['qty']).sum() \
    and (x['last_PO_code'].eq('105')*x['qty']).sum() == (x['last_PO_code'].eq('106')*x['qty']).sum() \
    else False

df2 = df.groupby(['class','item']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'regle1' : regle1(x),
                                  'regle2' : regle2(x),
                                  'regle3' : regle3(x),
                                  'regle4' : regle4(x),
                                  'regle5' : regle5(x),
                                  'regle6' : regle6(x),
                                  }))

#               regle1  regle2  regle3  regle4  regle5  regle6
#class  item                        
#0      1       True    False   False   False   False   False
#       2       False   True    False   False   False   False
#       3       False   True    True    False   False   False
#       4       False   False   False   False   True    False
#       5       False   False   False   False   True    True
```

PS. At this moment maybe it's time to use normal functions instead of lambdas, to have cleaner code :D. You also have repeatable chunks of code in your lambda, which could be easily automated.

PS2. I assumed, that in your example data, you have a typo (there shuld be `106` instead of `1046`

Comment: `x.loc[x['last_PO_code'].eq('103'), 'qty'].sum()` should be more efficient (avoiding the multiplication)

Comment: @mozway - I `%%timeit`'ed it and performance is similar(17,6 vs. 17,7 ms), but for sure using `.loc` is better for readability - I'll edit my answer

Comment: I also ran a few tests and multiplication is actually slightly faster, likely an overhead of `loc` vs pure array operations, my bad ;)